# How to use populate in Mongoose with multiple databases

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I have 2 mongodb databases `db1` `db2`

I have `model1`,`model2`,`model3` in `db1` and `model1`,`model2`,`model3` in `db2`

I want to populate from `db1.model2` to `db2.model3` like:

```
var Db1Model2 = db1.model('Model2', {
    'writer':{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Model3' }, // this line only works when all models are in one database. but I have (and need to have) multiple databases
    ....
});
```

How can I `ref` schema from a database to other for `populating`

Comment: Instead of a second property you should have a [binding converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your setter for `IsItemOld` doesn't change the value of the property, thus no property changed notifications will be sent. Use `SetValue(...)` in your `IsItemOld`to notify listeners of `IsItemOld`.

Comment: This is just a very very simple example. In my real situation I need to convert a `List` to `String` and reverse. like {1,2,3} -> "1,2,3" and "1,2,3"->{1,2,3} with properties getter and setters

Comment: @OmarZaarour has a far better answer than I, he is correct in saying you must use the SetValue(...) on IsItemOld.

Comment: But how about notify UI to read `IsItemOld` again when I set `IsItemNew` propery

Comment: I modified my answer to clarify a little.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SetValue of the IsItemNewProperty inside your setter instead of IsItemNew=...

Comment: You mean If I use `GetValue` and `SetValue` in `IsItemOld` for `IsItemNewProperty` it's corrects or sth. else